# PostgreSQL simple key vs composite key

Tags: postgresql, tree, hierarchy, composite-primary-key

We are going to store in PostgreSQL some info about organizations (in fact that is some entity, but I say "organization" just for clarity of structure). Each organization has 6 sublevels. First level - departments, second (inside departments) - sections etc. Each department (just like section and other) can have a unique name. We are thinking about 7 tables like

**Table organizations**

id (primary key) -- organization name

**Table level_1**

id (primary key) --  organization_id (foreign key) -- name

**Table level_2**

id (primary key) -- level_1_id (foreign key) -- name

etc

We suppose that on low levels (2-6) we can have thousands ob objects for each level. 
The question is how we should construct the primary key - as simple key (like described above) or composite key. F.i.

**Table level_1**

id (primary key) --  organization_id (primary key) -- name

**Table level_2**

id (primary key) -- level_1_id (primary key) -- name

etc

What key type is better (first of all, faster for SELECT queries) and why?
Thank you.

Comment: What kind of queries you're planning for? 'cos `... for SELECT queries` is way too broad definition of scope? Will you need to query for full hierarchies?

Comment: It can be various queries: select all orgs, select all depts in some org, select all sections in some dept of some org etc. So yes we are planning the queries for full hierarchies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it's a bad design.

What will you do if you need to add a level ?

- You'll need to add a table
- You'll need to modify all your code, views...

Not very scalable...

You should have only one table.

```
Organizations
Id   Parent_Id    Name
```

Data Sample:

```
1    NULL         Corporation
2       1         Division_1
3       1         Division_2
4       2         Dept_1_of_Division_1
5       2         Dept_2_of_Division_1
6       3         Dept_1_of_Division_2
```

To query this table, you would need to use [WITH RECURSIVE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: Thanks. I agree, but there some buts:

Comment: 1) We do not expect new levels. New level can appear (if they appear) only after lowest level, so it will not be difficult to create new table with foreign key to parent level. So there is no code modification.
2) You idea will cause a lot of replicas. F.i. org_name will be saved for every department, every section etc. Suppose we have 1000 deps and 1000 sections in each of them. So we have 1000*1000 of org_name replicas. The same thing for low level objects. That's why I don't want to store all data in one table.

Comment: 1) =) 2) could you explain? looks like i haven't got your idea. If i have only one table, I need to save all levels there. Org_name corresponds to its departments, section, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Need to think about it.

Comment: @user2498776 Your "a lot of replicas" shows that you don't understand how a relational DBMS works. A table is for facts with a certain combination of columns. If a value appears in another table then that is to record another fact. Normalization is (the main) way to reduce redundancy. It replaces a big table by smaller ones. Yet those smaller tables share columns and the values in them! Also, if this is your level of understanding then you should not worry about being "faster" until you learn more about straightforward schema design.

Comment: @philipxy Well, if you pay a little attention to initial design youl'll see that it is in 3NF. My comment about replicas was caused by misundersending of Luc M's idea, which he later clerified. So It'll much more interesting and useful for others if tell some useful things about db design, but not just "you don't understand" stuff. That is boring. really.

Comment: @user2498776 1. I don't know the exact order that answer & each comment were posted in 2. My first sentence was followed by an explanation. 3. You still suffer from the misunderstanding I explained. There's no need for ids; they are not preventing "replicas"; any "replicas" that would be in names from just using parent name and child name are present in Parent_Id and Name; there is nothing wrong with "replicas" per se, as explained in my previous comment; and Id is unnecessary. A table with Parent_Name and Name is equivalent to the one in the answer: you can construct one table from the other.